# What does the function __gnu_cxx::__stl_next_prime(usigned long) do?

Tags: c++, stl, gnu

I just saw that function in code, and intuitively it should return the next prime number greater than the argument. When I call it that way, however, I get 53! and then when I pass in 54 i get 97. I'm not finding a description of what it does online, can anybody point me to one or does anybody know what this does?

Comment: As a point of fact, there is no way to programattically generate a list of *all* primes efficiently. There are ways to calculate primes efficiently, but they won't produce a full list (there will be a lot of holes in the sequence, in other words). So this function can only be useful as an implementation detail of a specific operation.

Comment: @sidran32: You mean because there is an infinite number of prime numbers, and therefore there is no such thing as a complete list? Because prime number testing can be done pretty efficiently (of course definitions might vary, but it's not that too expensive) with a negliable error margin using randomized algorithms (for generating a full list sieve algorithms are better of course).

Comment: @Grizzly No, I'm talking about generating a sequence of prime numbers (say, Prime(n), where Prime(n + 1) is *guaranteed* to be the absolute next prime number after Prime(n) on the number line. There is no fast way to do this without brute-forcing, which become exponentially longer as you progress to larger values of n. There's ways to generate a prime number that is larger than one already known, but it's not necessarily the absolute next one on the number line.

Comment: @sidran32: Deterministic prime number testing can still be done in polynomial time and the distance between primenumbers is about proportional to their length, so it is not exponential time. Testing each number for primality isn't that bad of a method of getting the next prime number. Especially if, as is the case for most applications, you don't need to be a 100% sure that the number is prime (if the probability of the computer miscalculating is higher then the probability of the algorithm being wrong...). In that case randomized can do the job pretty nicely.

Comment: @Grizzly But because we don't have a sure-fire way of generating prime numbers without brute-forcing, we don't know if the pattern you suggest continues ad infinitum. Unless I'm mistaken, of course. I do know you can test from about sqrt(n), so maybe I overstated it? It still is very time-consuming. I was responding to the assumption the OP made, though. I can't imagine that it would be a generalized function that did as described since the usecases would probably require higher performance than you'd get.

Comment: @sidran32: Which pattern? Mathematics tells us that on average every `ln(n)`th number is prime (for big `n`). So to get the next prime you need to test about `ln(n)` numbers. Deterministic prime test is possible in something like `ln(n)^6`. In the typical case where a (extremely small) possibility for false positives is acceptable the runtime can be much smaller using randomized algorithms. Thus finding the next prime has polynomial runtime in regards to the length of `n`, which is pretty good. Of course in this case the primes are probably hardcoded, since everything else would be overkill.

Comment: @Grizzly That is a good point. That was what I was referring to, more or less. I didn't make that connection.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It returns the next prime that is sufficiently greater than the specified prime to be worth reorganizing a hash table to that number of buckets. If it returned the very next prime, you'd be reorganizing your hash tables *way* too often. It is an implementation detail of the hash table code and it's not meant to be used by outside code.

Comment: Ah I see, do you know what the gyst of the algorithm used is? Something like next prime at least twice as big? Or something more complicated?

Comment: It's a fixed look up table. I don't know the exact algorithm they used, but typically, you multiply by some amount around 2, then find a prime near there that's not too close to a power of 2. (If you're really diligent, you test how good the primes are with 'typical' data.) The table is: 53 97 193 389 769 1543 3079 6151 12289 24593 49157 98317 196613 393241 786433 1572869 3145739 6291469 12582917 25165843 50331653 100663319 201326611 402653189 805306457 1610612741 3221225473 4294967291